# Swift Closure Modify Outside Variable For Collection View

Tags: swift, geolocation, uicollectionview, closures

I've been trying to set an external variable within a closure that runs an asynchronous query for a location that a user chooses so that I can use that data to calculate values for a cell in a collection view (i.e use the location within the cellForItemAtIndexPath function). The variable begins as the user's current location, and updates once the user decides on a location. The variable does change while inside the closure; however, once outside the closure, the variable returns to the user's current location and not the one the user just chose. How can I make the variable change permanent?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have been using

Comment: It sounds like you're having an async timing issue. Please post the code.